# How to port forward kubernetes to local

Tags: kubernetes

I have done with

```
kubectl port-forward <name> <port1:port2>,
```

but I'm still getting "This site can’t be reached" when go to http://localhost:/
I'm hosting my k8s cluster on GKE.

What a config that I have to add to my local? is there any configuration that I have to add to my /etc/hosts?

Thank You!

It's running well on my local with docker container run, but in kubernetes cluster, when I do port-forward, I was stuck.

```
kubectl run demo --image=cloudnatived/demo:hello --port=8888 --labels app=demo
```

I'm trying port-forward after executed the command.

```
kubectl port-forward demo 9999:8888
```

then go to http://localhost:9999

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Are you connecting to the `port1`; does the `port2` match the port the service in the Pod is listening on; have you verified in other ways that the Pod and the underlying image are functional?  Editing `/etc/hosts` is almost never necessary and you don't need to do it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. It's my fault. I didn't check my kubeconfig. turn out, my kubeconfig still use a previous cluster. So it's why I can't connect when using a port-forward. So, what I was doing, because I'm using GKE

1. check kubernetes version

   gke-gcloud-auth-plugin --version
2. connect to the cluster using terminal with this command

   gcloud container clusters get-credentials [CLUSTER_NAME] --zone [YOUR_ZONE] --project [PROJECT_NAME]
3. view kube config

   kubectl config view

Then do

```
kubectl port-forward [POD_NAME] [LOCALHOST_PORT]:[POD_PORT]
```

Answer (score 0):

**kubectl port-forward mongo-75f59d57f4-4nd6q(pod_name) 28015:27017**

for your reference : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/

if you can share error then exact issue .

Answer (score 0):

**Below troubleshooting steps will help you to resolve your issue:**

- You can check below syntax once whether you are properly giving the correct Port numbers and Pod name. If you want to forward to a different port in localhost, then it should be in this format :
  `kubectl port-forward <pod-name> <localhost-port>:<pod-port>`

  `The above command forwards to localhost Port from pod Port`. Check for more commands [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#port-forward).
- Using this port forward we can forward TCP Traffic and TCP Ports only and hence make sure you have only TCP Ports.
- Ensure that the service you are trying to access is running and is accessible within the Kubernetes cluster. You can use the `kubectl get services` command to check the status of your services.
- Refer to this [blog](https://inlets.dev/blog/2022/06/24/fixing-kubectl-port-forward.html) written by Alex Ellis which describes the issues with kubectl port forwarding and ways to overcome it.

Comment: Sure, it's quite helpful, particularly the blog information. I have found the issue, it is in KubeConfig. in turn, I still use a previous KubeConfig cluster, it's why I can't use port-forward locally. Thank you

Comment: @asz : If the answer has some useful information can you upvote the answer for greater visibility.